Run docker compose build --no-cache return error unix:///.supervisor.sock no such file
Im trying to buld a docker img with php8 and apache, but when restart apache in the line RUN service apache2 restart, return this  error , this is dockerfile:
FROM webdevops/php-apache:8.2

# we need libaio!
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libaio1 libaio-dev

ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /tmp/
ADD instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /tmp/
ADD instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /tmp/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_12_2 /usr/local/instantclient
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/instantclient_12_2/

# install
RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient' | pecl install oci8
RUN echo "extension=oci8" > $(pecl config-get ext_dir)/oci8.ini

# don't know if this is necessary
RUN docker-php-ext-enable oci8
# RUN ldd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/oci8.so
# RUN ldconfig

#restart apache
RUN service apache2 restart

#show if oci8 is present
RUN php -i | grep oci8

# export ports
EXPOSE 80 443


thanks!!
fix the problem and build the docker

What line exactly is producing the error?  Nothing in your Dockerfile mentions supervisord (and you shouldn't usually need it), how is it involved here?

in the RUN service apache2 restart line, idk

In a comment, you cite this line as the problem:
RUN service apache2 restart

You can safely delete this line.
A Docker image doesn't include any running processes.  Instead, it contains the image's filesystem and some metadata describing what to do when the container starts.  If you change a configuration file in a Dockerfile, you don't need to restart the service: it's not running right now, and when you eventually docker run a container from the image, it will start its process for the first time, and that will read the configuration file.
Since a container only runs a single process, it doesn't generally run any sort of process manager, and so service, systemctl, and similar commands frequently don't work.  Your image seems to have a setup where service tries to interact with a supervisord, but again, that's not running during the image build, so RUN service ... fails with the error you show.  You shouldn't usually need to run service at all in a Docker context, and it won't typically work.

Thanks!!, deleting that line, works ok
